# C++ Access to SQL Server from Linux

Tags: c++, sql, linux, sql-server-2005, odbc

I need to write some data to SQL Server database from Linux in C++.

I found this **sqlapi.com**

But I think, at first ODBC driver has to be installed and has to work.

I folowed this
adminlife.net/allgemein/mssql-zugriff-unter-debian-etch-mit-unixodbc-und-freetds/
or this
http://b.gil.megiteam.pl/2009/11/linux-odbc-to-mssql/

But it didn't work. The port 1433 seems to be closed 
($ sudo nmap -PN -sU -p 1433 192.168.56.101 -> port "filtered")

isql -v sqlexpress sa
-> wait with no response or get "couldn't connect to sql"

From other PC with Windows I have no problem to write data in SQL Server, 
so server should be right configured to remote access.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are the links I bookmarked concerning that topic, hope it can help you:

- [ODBC Tutorial](http://www.easysoft.com/developer/languages/c/odbc_tutorial.html)
- [FreeTDS](http://www.freetds.org/)
- [Connection strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/default.aspx)
- [How to configure ODBC](http://www.unixodbc.org/doc/FreeTDS2.html) - This one was really useful.

It was some time ago, but basically what I remember is:

You have to create an entry for the particular MSSQL driver you have in a file named **/etc/odbcinst.ini**. Then, for each MSSQL server, you have to create an entry (or **DSN**), either globaly in **/etc/odbc.ini**, or user-local, in **$HOME/.odbc.ini**.

Some names I used might differ (and I don't have acces to my Linux box right now to check) but you got the general idea.

Once you did that, **isql -d**  should connect succesfully to the database. If so, then using the C/Linux API for ODBC should be a piece of cake. Tutorials provided in the given links.

Comment: Oh and I remember that some tweaking has to be done on the MSSQL Server itself. You must allow TCP connections and access using login/password.

Answer (score 4):

FreeTDS is what you want.  "FreeTDS is a set of libraries for Unix and Linux that allows your programs to natively talk to Microsoft SQL Server and Sybase databases."

[http://www.freetds.org](http://www.freetds.org/)

Comment: nothing new for me, didnt help, i made all of this, there is the same procedure in links I have posted..

Comment: If you can't find port 1433 open on the SQL server box, then you have a problem unrelated to the libraries you're using.

Comment: But 'www.freetds.org' is not.  Fixed.